# NullPointerException in a few real devices while parsing JSON with Gson

Tags: android, arraylist, gson, android-glide

I a have JSON file that I am loading from storage and parsing with Gson. In 10% of devices that are launching the app, it will crash on a specific line.

I installed the app on other Android phones but none of them crashed on that line.

First I read the file and parse it with Gson like:

```
new Gson().fromJson(FileManager.readFile(new File(json)), listType)
```

list type:

```
listType = new TypeToken<ThirdPartyServerModel>(){}.getType();
```

JSON file:

```
 {
 "accepted_values": {
  "policy_term": [
         2,
         3,
         4,
         6,
        12
     ]
  }
```

My POJO class ThirdPartyServerModel:

```
@AutoValue
public class ThirdPartyServerModel implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("accepted_values")
    public AcceptedValues acceptedValues;

@AutoValue
public static class AcceptedValues {
    @SerializedName("liability_property_damage")
    public List<String> liabilityPropertyDamage;

    @SerializedName("policy_term")
    public List<Integer> policyTerm;

}}
```

Error line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 
      thirdPartyServerModels.acceptedValues.policyTerm.size(); i++) {
            policyTerms.add(new SimpleItem(null));
   }}
```

Error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 
'ThirdPartyServerModel.acceptedValues' on a null object reference
```

Why is this happening just on some device ,not all of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your JSON is not valid

I think you forgot to add {}

now is working I tested the code below

```
public class ThirdPartyServerTest {

    String json =
            "{\"accepted_values\": {\n" + " \"policy_term\": [\n" + "        2,\n" + "        3,\n" + "        4,\n" + "        6,\n" + "        12\n"
                    + "    ]\n" + " } }";

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //given
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ThirdPartyServerModel>() {
        }.getType();
        //when
        ThirdPartyServerModel model = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
        //then
        assertEquals(5, model.acceptedValues.policyTerm.size());
        assertEquals(new Integer(12), model.acceptedValues.policyTerm.get(4));
    }

}
```

Comment: that's my typing  mistake in question, actually it's correct.  it's working in 95 percent of device but not all of them.

Comment: @HoseinHaqiqian 
I think this is a problem with the file. 
1. Always display the String you are now parsing
2. if you have this device that does not work, see if it will work with mock data(NOT file)